# How do I get my ionic app to work in my Android Phone

Tags: android

I am writing my First Ionic and Node express API. Node JS is a simple http get which gets top 10 rows from a db. Ionic has a button, onclick calls the http address. The URL works from my chrome browser on my phone. But when I create the APK from ionic and copy/install the APK, the button does not respond with any data in the installed app. Here is the Node CORS:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var port = process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 1337;
    var cors = require('cors')  //use this
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

My ionic app:

**Home.page.ts has this code:**

```
runHttp() {

   this.http.get('http://111.111.111.42:9003/api/products')
   .subscribe(data => {
     this.friends=data;

   });
```

**Home.page.html has this button:**

```
 <div id="container">
    <ion-button (click)="runHttp()">Show all Items</ion-button>
    <ion-grid [class]="tableTheme">
      <ion-row [class]="tableHeader">
        <ion-col class="ion-text-bold"> SKU </ion-col>
        <ion-col class="ion-text-bold"> Description </ion-col>

      </ion-row>
      <ion-row *ngFor="let friend of friends">
        <ion-col class="ion-text-bold">{{ friend.PID }}</ion-col>
        <ion-col class="ion-text-bold">{{ friend.LongDescription }}</ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>

   </div>
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance to all!

Comment: FYI: ** NOTE the URL address  below is a outside IP address forwarded to an internal address internal port of 1337. (the address below is not the real ip. As stated the actual address in the app works on the browser on my phone and my Windows PC)
   this.http.get('http://111.111.111.42:9003/api/products')

Answer (score 0):

In the AndroidManifest.xml make sure you have enabled the internet for your app using the below tag.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```